# Comprobar contraseña

Tags: java, android

He hecho un formulario para que el usuario introduzca unos datos y guardarlos en una BD local, lo que quiero hacer es teniendo 2 campos de contraseña (uno para la contraseña y otro para comprobarla) crear una función que comprueba que la contraseña del primer y del segundo campo son la misma.

He hecho un boceto de una función y quería saber si se podría hacer así o hay alguna manera mejor.

```
public boolean repeatedPass(String pass){
    String contrasenyaComprobar = campoContrasenya.getText().toString();
    String pass2 = "equal";
    if(pass.equals(pass2) || contrasenyaComprobar.isEmpty()){
        return pass == null;
    }
}
```

Falta el return del final porque no tenia claro como colocarlo.

Se agradece la ayuda.

Comment: La comprobación debería ser más bien así: `boolean isValid=true; if ( !pass.equals(pass2) || contrasenyaComprobar.isEmpty() ) { isValid=false; } return isValid;` Aquí simplemente se crea la variable de comprobación con valor `true` por defecto y sólo cambia a `false` si las cadenas no son iguales (nótese que puse `!` en el `equals`) o si el texto está vacío. Aunque para trabajar con contraseñas, [necesitarás algo más avanzado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2861125/5587982), si quieres proteger en serio las contraseñas.

Answer (score 1):

Para comprobar si dos campos `String` son iguales basta con usar el metodo `equals` de `String` directamente.

```
if(pass!=null && pass.equals(pass2)){
    // Son iguales
}else{
    // No son iguales
}
```

Si lo quieres en método

```
public boolean sonIguales(String pass, String pass2){
    return pass!=null && pass.equals(pass2);
}
```